# what is the right way to use XMPPAutoTime in xmppframework for iOS

Tags: ios, xmppframework

I need some help on integrating `XMPPAutoTime` module in `xmppframework` in my project. I need my time to be synced with the server time. For this I am using the following code.

```
@property (nonatomic,strong,readonly) XMPPAutoTime *autotime;

 autotime=[[XMPPAutoTime alloc] initWithDispatchQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
[autotime activate:xmppStream];
[autotime addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
```

I am assuming that this syncs the time with the server and I am using this `autotime.date` property to get time everywhere in the project. I am assuming this will be the server synced time. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this code is correct. You also need to implement a method in `XMPPAutoTimeDelegate` to check when XMPPAutoTime got the time from server as follows:

```
extension AppDelegate: XMPPAutoTimeDelegate {
  func xmppAutoTime(sender: XMPPAutoTime!, didUpdateTimeDifference timeDifference: NSTimeInterval) {
    print("time difference = \(timeDifference)")
  }
}
```